# How can I derive a table from another table in Excel using this SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, group-by

<sub>(this question belongs either at SuperUser or StackOverflow - can't quite decide.)</sub>

I have an Excel table - let's call it t1 - with columns c1, c2, c3.

I want to obtain the following table based on t1:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, min_c3
FROM 
  t1,
  (SELECT c1, MIN(c3) AS min_c3 GROUP BY c1) AS t2
WHERE
  t1.c1 = t2.c1
  t1.c3 = t2.min_c3;
```

... in Excel. (Actually, the query is even more complex, but let's keep it simpler for the sake of this question.) As far as I know, Excel does not directly support SQL queries for creating new table data.

Other than exporting the data from Excel and using a proper DBMS - what's the most straightforward/least-convoluted way to be able to create the new table using the query and the old table data?

Notes:

- It would be even better if the resulting table would change dynamically as data in table t1 changes, but that's not a strict requirement.
- Solution can involve using VBA, Excel Add-Ins, etc.

Example:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| green | 2 | 100 |
| green | 3 | 50 |
| blue | 1 | 200 |

should result in:

| c1 | c2 | min_c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| green | 3 | 50 |
| blue | 1 | 200 |

Comment: `BYROW()` with few additional function may give you desired result. Show some sample data then expected output.

Comment: @Harun24hr: Added a bit of sample data and output, and also tweaked the query.

Comment: "I want to obtain the following table based on t1 ..." Executing sql on a range/table you take the result as a recordset object, not as a new table. Is that you want or need to copy the result in a new area in sheet and trasmform that area from range  to table ?

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ: Eventually, I want a new table: To be able to view and to create charts off of. So, I believe I want the second option you listed.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:A4),y,MAXIFS(B2:B4,A2:A4,x),z,MINIFS(C2:C4,A2:A4,x),HSTACK(x,y,z))
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work; can you link to explanations of what LET, UNIQUE, MAXIFS and HSTACK do? Also, will this be adaptible to a case where an additional level of inner aggregation is necessary (i.e. there's a table T3 which contributes to T2 which in turn contributes to the result)?

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike I will make an explanation. Basically `SQL` and excel functions works on different way. So, we can't think of inner aggregation but based on data and expected output we can use different functions and apply some tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Using your SQL created a sub to do the job. If have any questions on what or why let me know.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Call tester
End Sub

Sub tester()
   ' CALL THE SUB WITH TWO ARGUMENTS:
   ' 1. THE RANGE OF THE ORIGINAL TABLE (use the range for general use)
   ' 2. a RANGE (one cell only) as destination position to start the copy of the results
   Call newTableOfTable(Me.ListObjects("TABLE_MASTER").Range, Me.Range("E1"), "TABLE_RESULTS")
End Sub

' ON PARAMETER rng EXECUTE an SQL command AND WITH THE RESULT
' CREATE A NEW TABLE AT POSITION destination WITH NAME  nameOfNewTable
Sub newTableOfTable(rng As Range, destination As Range, nameOfNewTable As String)
   Dim connection As Object, recSet As Object, sql As String, table As String, c As Long
   'create the sql "table name" as VBA recognize it
   table = " [" & rng.Worksheet.Name & "$" & rng.Address(0, 0) & "] "
   
   ' create the sql command, if you need an order by append it to the end
   sql = "SELECT T1.[c1], T1.[c2], T2.[min_c3]  FROM " & table & " T1, (SELECT [c1], MIN([c3]) AS min_c3 FROM " & table & _
         " GROUP BY [c1]) T2 WHERE T1.[c1] = T2.[c1] AND T1.[c3]=T2.[min_c3] " 'ORDER BY
   Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   With connection
      .CursorLocation = 3
      .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
      .Open
      Set recSet = .Execute(sql)
   End With
   If Not destination Is Nothing Then
      With destination
         ' DELETE any TABLE AT DESTINATION POSITION (if exist one)
         If Not .ListObject Is Nothing Then
            .ListObject.Delete
         End If
         ' copy as headers the names of the result columns
         For c = 0 To recSet.Fields.Count - 1
            .Offset(0, c).Value2 = recSet.Fields(c).Name
         Next
         ' copy the data begining from second line of destination (first are the headrs)
         Call .Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset(recSet)
         ' make the destinarion as big as the headers and the data
         Set destination = .Resize(recSet.recordCount + 1, recSet.Fields.Count)
         ' tranform the range of destination to TABLE and give it the name coming with the third parameter
         .Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, destination, , xlYes).Name = nameOfNewTable
      End With
   End If
   ' close and clear objects
   recSet.Close
   connection.Close
   Set recSet = Nothing
   Set connection = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I think if you append the language name to the ``` marks, it'll work. ... there, fixed it.

Comment: I deleted some comments thinking it would be formatted correctly...